# Evaluate Available Updates to True or False with powershell in windows

Tags: windows, powershell

I'm trying to make a script that evaluates to TRUE or FALSE based on if there are windows update available on the target server. I know that **Get-WUList** will list all available updates, but is there a way to make this return a boolean?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just count the list it returns.

```
(Get-WUList).count
```

Returns 0 or the amount of updates.

If you need it as a strict boolean:

```
(Get-WUList).count -ne 0
```

Comment: Thank you! This is working great.